# Change event on input not being fired from angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

Why is this change event that I add to an input element from an angular directive not being fired when the marked input element loses focus?

UPDATE: The [jqlite docs say](https://code.google.com/p/jqlite/wiki/UsingJQLite) - "a subset of the operations which jQuery supports are currently implemented"... and they specifically list `.change` under event handlers. The current answers contradict this, but I'd like to hear the authors explicitly say "the docs are wrong", or "your understanding of the docs is wrong". Currently it looks like the they have skimmed the first few lines and gone no further. No-one learns if I adopt a different way when actually there's another mistake that I haven't caught and I could easily make again.

```
app.directive('changeDirective', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      return elem.change(function() {
        alert("Change!");
      });
    }
  };
});

<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    input with change listener<input type="text" change-directive="true">
    <br/>
    select this to remove focus from other input <input type="number">
  </body>
</html>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rb76W7DrQZtvbQ7LOS6L?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Angular.js uses `jqLite` as a jQuery replacement and it doesn't have all of jQuery's functions.

> jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular
>   to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite
>   implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal
>   of having a very small footprint.

Try using the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead:

```
return elem.on('change', function() {
    alert("Change!");
});
```

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wjkg2bDauSXoPYYO0SR7?p=preview)

Check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for more info about `angular.element`.

[Here is a list of all jqLite functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite).

Comment: See my update. This angular list of functions differs from the jqLite docs. Are they out of synch? https://code.google.com/p/jqlite/wiki/UsingJQLite

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, AngularJS uses [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), a subset of jQuery which does not include a `.change` method. You should use `.on` instead.

Secondly, the `change` event does not trigger when an element loses focus. Use the `blur` event instead. You can use both the `blur` and `change` events together if you use the `.on` method.

**Code:**

```
return elem.on('blur change', function() {
    alert('Change!');
});
```

[**Demo on Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DC0GoJ7Ex0I9vmgE6v7z?p=preview)

Comment: See my update - I appreciate yours works and mine doesn't but the docs explicitly say that `.change` _is_ supported. Unless you're saying that Angular jqLite is different from this jqLite? https://code.google.com/p/jqlite/wiki/UsingJQLite

Comment: @FritzMeissner I checked [Angular's jqLite source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js). I couldn't find any mention of a `.change` method

Comment: So you're saying that these are different implementations of jqlite?